# how to enable selector in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Say I write a jquery plugin (all it does is make text red on a selected element ) like so:

```
jQuery.fn.testPlugin = function(options){
    // default plugin settings
    settings = jQuery.extend({
        el: 'p'

    }, options);

    $(function () {

        $(settings.el).css('color', 'red');

    }); // end ready

} // end jQuery.fn.testPlugin
```

Then, say I have a `<p>` which I want to color red, I would call my plugin like so:

```
$().testPlugin('p');
```

What I don't know and wish to know is, how could I make the selector work inside the `$()`, so that I can do the following and get the same effect, without the `el` inside the settings.

```
$('p').testPlugin();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally `this` would return to current selector:

```
jQuery.fn.testPlugin = function(options){
  return this.each(function(){
    //having code here assigns like you wanted : $('p').testPlugin();
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  });
};
```

Now, you can apply this:

```
$('p').testPlugin();
```

---

But since if you wanted to have both way:

Just use the following way:

```
jQuery.fn.testPlugin = function(options){
    // code you're having and below code:
    if(settings.el == undefined){
       return this.each(function(){
           //rest of my above code
      });
   }
} // end jQuery.fn.testPlugin
```